# Syntax error on token ",", invalid BlockStatements in Eclipse Java

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor

```
public BasePlusCommissionEmployee(String firstName, String lastName,
           String socialSecurityNumber, double grossSales.
           double commissionRate, double baseSalary)
{

    super(firstName, lastName, socialSecurityNumber,grossSales,commissionRate);
    if(baseSalary < 0.0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Base Salary is invalid");

    this.baseSalary = baseSalary;
}
```

This is my constructor.

I don't know why Eclipse is showing errors. Please guide me.

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ",", invalid 
     BlockStatements
    - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
    - Syntax error on token ".", , expected
    - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
    - Syntax error on token ".", ; expected

These are the errors

Comment: You have a `.` behind `grossSales` instead of `,`

Comment: Please show the code including the class definition, and the parent class as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have a full stop in between `double grossSales` and `double commissionRate`

change

```
double grossSales. double commissionRate,
```

to

```
double grossSales, double commissionRate,
```

Comment: Thank you. I cant believe I miss that.